# Can we use the resolution we want in the esp32 cam module?

Tags: arduino-esp32

I want to use 256x256 resolution. This is not available in the resolutions offered to me.
I am working with wificam example via esp32 wrover module.
I have an artificial intelligence model and this model makes predictions at a resolution of 256x256.

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the image, that would be a faster solution, compared to resizing. The closest resolutions are 320x240 and 400x296. You can take a picture at 400x296 and crop the center or another region to your target resolution.

Resolutions: https://esphome.io/components/esp32_camera.html

A sample of how to crop:
https://simplyexplained.com/blog/esp32-cam-cropping-images-on-device/

The question says esp32-cam, for OV2640 there's also FRAMESIZE_CIF (352 x 288) which is closer to your target:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-ov2640-camera-settings/